# Unable to prepopulate value in the dropdown for angular reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have one form group which used both for create and edit screen. Create page is working as expected. But in Edit page text box and drop-down should be pre-populate with the value.In my case using below piece of code I am able to populate value for text-box but not for drop-down.
Here is my code:

```
create.ts - >
//this is for group
createBindingForm = new FormGroup({
    bindingId: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
    bindingType: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
  });


//Method to pre-populate value while click on edit.

preFillForm(binding: Binding) {
    this.createBindingForm.value.bindingId = binding.businessObject.id; // this is working fine.
    this.createBindingForm.controls['bindingType'].setValue(binding.businessObject.type.value,{onlySelf: true}); // Not working
}
```

Create.html - >

```
<form [formGroup]="createBindingForm" class="form">
<div class="form-input-row">
      <section class="form-input-item">
        <label class="input-label" [class.error]="bindingId.errors && (bindingId.dirty || bindingId.touched || formSubmitAttempt)" >
          Business Id <span class="red">*</span>
        </label>
      <label class="input-label">
         <input type="text" formControlName="bindingId" [class.error]="bindingId.errors && (bindingType.dirty || bindingType.touched || formSubmitAttempt)" [disabled]="isUpdating" required autocomplete="off">
      </label>
        <div *ngIf="bindingId.errors && (bindingId.dirty || bindingId.touched || formSubmitAttempt)" class="alert alert-danger">
          <div class="error-message" [hidden]="!bindingId.errors.required">
            Please provide a business Id
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <span class="row-item-spacer"></span>
      <section class="form-input-item">
        <label class="input-label" [class.error]="bindingType.errors && (bindingType.dirty || bindingType.touched || formSubmitAttempt)">
          Binding Type <span class="red">*</span>
        </label>
      <label class="input-label">
        <select class="custom-select" formControlName="bindingType" class="drop-down" [class.error]="bindingType.errors && (bindingType.dirty || bindingType.touched || formSubmitAttempt)" [disabled]="isUpdating" required>
          <option value="" disabled>Select</option>
          <option *ngFor="let bindingtype of bindingtype" [ngValue]="bindingtype">{{bindingtype.value}}</option>
        </select>
      </label>
        <div *ngIf="bindingType.errors && (bindingType.dirty || bindingType.touched || formSubmitAttempt)" class="alert alert-danger">
          <div class="error-message" [hidden]="!bindingType.errors.required">
            Please select the binding type
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
</form>
```

Model :

```
businessObject: {
    id: string;
    type: {
      label: string;
      value: string;
    }
  };
```

Can someone help for dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
preFillForm(binding: Binding) {
    this.createBindingForm.controls[bindingId].patchValue(binding.businessObject.id);
    this.createBindingForm.controls[bindingType].patchValue(binding.businessObject.type.value);
}
```

Comment: Tried.. Still not working for drop-down which is "bindingType" but text-box is working.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not share it.

Comment: You can create a dummy one, without any real info